# crontab doesn't execute python file on reboot

Tags: python, cron

In crontab I have:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /root/mydirectory/mypythonfile.py
```

Using: `which python3` I get:  `/usr/bin/python3`

at the start of the python script I have: `#!/usr/bin/python3`

The python file is executable for everyone.

Running `./mypythonfile.py` in shell works o.k.

I have no idea left what to do, to make this file execute via crontab. I played in crontab and executed some commands (not python script) and it worked fine.

I am logged in as Root, so this should not be a problem as well.

EDIT:
How do I know it's not running?

I created a script, which sends e-mail, inserts dummy data in database and I checked Htop for .py file. Zero on all.

Comment: Perhaps the things your script is trying to do are not possible at reboot? maybe the email server / database server are not yet ready to accept connections?

Comment: Insert a sleep command someplace for a couple of minutes to give network time to come up.

Comment: Also check `/var/log/syslog` file or run `journalctl -xe -b-0` and check for error messages.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yes, this worked. I have figured it out MySQL was not active at the same time scrip has started. I added sleep time and now it works. Thank you.

Comment: @steeldriver I monitored stuff. When you reoobt system not all the stuff was active while script has already started. this was a conflict for script not working.

Comment: Can I suggest you answer your own question now you have a solution. This particular answer could be very useful to others and if it is answered it will be easier to find

Comment: @PonJar Sure thing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As @WinEunuuchs2Unix mentioned it is good to set up sleep time before python execution, given the fact python script may include services (example: MySQL), which are not active immediately on reboot.

the solution for my case is:

```
@reboot sleep 300 && /usr/bin/python3 /root/mydirectory/mypythonfile.py
```